# Multiple windows in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide

I work with multiple monitors and I like to use several Eclipse windows and move the editors using drag and drop.

In the last versions (4.2+) I can't make this feature to work again.

For example in Kepler when I drag a editor it appears in a new small window, but without the  menus (File/Edit/Run/etc) and toolbars.

How can I make drag and drop to work again like in previous version?

**Drag and drop in JUNO**

[image]

**Drag and drop in KEPLER**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its not exactly Drag And Drop, but you can click on Window >> New Window, and you'll have 2 windows with all the options, and you'll be able to open files on both...

Comment: But you will only be able to open a file directly in the window you want, you can not drag from one window to the other.